# Should we burninate the [social] countryside?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social) has 755 questions. From what I can tell, it's got a wide variety of topics as is, including social media, social plugins, socialite, and so on. I don't think we can really even classify someone as an expert on [social](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social) given the broad range of topics. It seems to qualify for the burninate requirements due to all of these. An equivalent tag for this would be like having a tag for [business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business) in questions that relate to business, almost.

So, is this a candidate for burnination?

Comment: It also doesn't have a tag wiki and feels like the uses related to something like Twitter or Facebook are useless without another tag.  Unleash Trogdor.

Comment: The only purpose of such a tag would be community management where you can be an expert no matter which social network we're talking about... but that's off topic so let it burn.

Comment: Let the record show that @Compass is anti-social.

Comment: I would also close some of those questions... they are pretty bad examples there.

Comment: @KirkWoll forever arone Q.Q